# iOS Perform Segue from handler of Unwind Segue gives Unbalanced Calls to begin/end appearance transitions

Tags: ios, uistoryboard

I have an app which shows a set of introductory screens when first launched. The segue to these screens is launched in the initial view controller's -viewDidLoad method. There are a couple of buttons, which are linked to exit segues in the initial view controller. One of these buttons simply has the exit segue performed, and then the initial view controller takes over. Another button has the exit segue performed, but then in the initial view controller's handler, it issues a performSegue to another screen. Once this happens, though, I get the message, "Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for ". I have -prepareForSegue doing what it should be doing, and I haven't seen multiple calls to that. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as it turns out, there was a delegate call that happened before launching the segue, which brought the app back to the first view controller as well. This caused the stack to pop back, and so when control returned, the segue couldn't be executed because there was no Navigation Controller. Either I had to live with the delegate call and make that work, or remove the delegate call. Fortunately, it wasn't doing much, so I was able to remove it.